# Spring MVC not being called by the Angular JS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, angularjs-http

I'm trying to intgrate Angular JS with an existing Spring MVC project.
I had à problem calling a Spring controller from the Angular JS controller.

This is my `app.js`:

```
'use strict';
var AdminApp = angular.module('AdminApp',[]);
```

And the service:

```
'use strict';

AdminApp.factory('AdminService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        fetchAllTerminals: function() {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8081/crmCTI/admin/terminal')
                    .success(function(response) {
                        console.log('Service');
                        return response.data;
                    })
                    .error(function(errResponse) {
                        console.error('Error while fetching terminals');
                        return $q.reject(errResponse);
                    });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and the controller:

```
'use strict';

AdminApp.controller('AdminController', ['$scope', 'AdminService', function($scope, AdminService) {
    var self = this;
    self.terminal={id:'',connectedUser:'',type:'',state:''};
    self.terminals=[];

    self.fetchAllTerminals = function() {
        console.log('Controller');
        AdminService.fetchAllTerminals()
        .success(function() {
            self.terminals = d;
        })
        .error(function() {
            console.error('Error while fetching Terminals');
        });
    };

    self.reset = function() {
        self.terminal = {id : null, connectedUser : '', type : '', state : ''};
    };
}]);
```

The `JSP` I'm using to display the data is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head></head>

<body ng-app="AdminApp" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
    <div ng-controller="AdminController as adminController">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Login</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="terminal in adminController.terminals">
                    <td>{{terminal.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{terminal.connectedUser}}</td>
                    <td>{{terminal.type}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/vendors/angular/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/controller/admin-controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/service/admin-service.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can access my Spring Controller from a web browser and it returns some data but it's not being called by the Angular JS controller

Am I missing something here?
Could you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: why use jps when you are using angular?

Comment: Well, I followed [this](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/) tutorial. What should I use instead?

Comment: use html and angular directly, you don't need to have a jsp page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a data from your service function you should use `.then` function which has ability to return a data when promise gets resolved OR reject. That you can't to with `.success` & `.error` function.

> `.success` & `.error` method of `$http` has been [**deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

**Factory**

```
AdminApp.factory('AdminService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        fetchAllTerminals: function() {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8081/crmCTI/admin/terminal')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log('Service');
                        return response.data;
                    },function(errResponse) {
                        console.error('Error while fetching terminals');
                        return $q.reject(errResponse);
                    });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then controller method will again place `.then` function on the factory method. So the 1st function of `.then` will get called on resolved of `fetchAllTerminals` call, if it gets rejected 2nd function will get called.

**Controller**

```
self.fetchAllTerminals = function() {
    console.log('Controller');
    AdminService.fetchAllTerminals()
    .then(function(data) {
        self.terminals = data;
    }, function(error) {
        console.error('Error while fetching Terminals');
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I did use `then` and it didn't work either, that's why I tryied this way

Comment: @user2490936 sorry.. I actually I missed the controller part too..so try it now..should work now..

Comment: weren't success and error legacy way to use $http service?

Comment: @Gianmarco `.success` & `.error` method of `$http` are deprecated.

Comment: All right, i'll re-try `then` method and see if it works. thank you guys

Comment: @Gianmarco yes..its not standard way to deal with async call in angular.actually its not deprecated, but I can disable this by setting some configuration in $http leagacy

Comment: Hi, still not working... I'm stuck. Is it because I'm using `JSP` in the Spring project?

Comment: The server returns `JSON` data when I call the controller from a web browser but it's never called from my angular js javascript code

Comment: I solved the problem by using `ngResource`.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('AdminApp',[]);
```

And the service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('AdminApp').factory('AdminService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        fetchAllTerminals: function() {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8081/crmCTI/admin/terminal')
                    .success(function(response) {
                        console.log('Service');
                        return response.data;
                    })
                    .error(function(errResponse) {
                        console.error('Error while fetching terminals');
                        return $q.reject(errResponse);
                    });
        }
    };
}]);
```

controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('AdminApp').controller('AdminController', ['$scope', 'AdminService', function($scope, AdminService) {
    var self = this;
    self.terminal={id:'',connectedUser:'',type:'',state:''};
    self.terminals=[];

    self.fetchAllTerminals = function() {
        console.log('Controller');
        AdminService.fetchAllTerminals()
        .success(function() {
            self.terminals = d;
        })
        .error(function() {
            console.error('Error while fetching Terminals');
        });
    };

    self.reset = function() {
        self.terminal = {id : null, connectedUser : '', type : '', state : ''};
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Why? do you have any solution? I'm new to angular :)

Comment: `.success` & `error` method are basically a follows callback pattern. it can't return data to follow promise chain..so you need to use `.then` which can return a data.